# F# async/await in a viewmodel

Tags: mvvm, f#, async-await, fsharp.viewmodule

### My ViewModel in F#

I'm trying to use F# instead of C# to implement my ViewModel.
I'm following this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394149.aspx) (btw, is there something newer or any better suggestion?).

So let's say that I have my view model base implementation (`MVVM.ViewModel`, it's in C# but I can reference it from F#) and a simple `Status` property.

```
namespace FuncViewModel
open MVVM.ViewModel
open System

    type MyFuncViewModel() = 
        inherit ViewModelBase()

        let mutable status=""

        member this.RunSetStatus() =
            status <- "Reset @" + DateTime.Now.ToString "yy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss"
            base.OnPropertyChanged("Status")

        member this.SetStatus = new DelegateCommand(fun _ -> this.RunSetStatus() )


    member this.Status 
        with get() =
            status
        and set(value) =
             status <- value
             base.OnPropertyChanged(fun () -> this.Status)
```

Everything works as expected, *so far so good* (but let me know if you spot any conceptual error or if you find a more idiomatic version for the above code)

### Introducing the async/await pattern

This is where I'm going wrong: I know how to do that in C# but I'm not good at it in F#.

I've tried with the following.

```
member this.RunSetStatus() =
    status <- "Start resetting @" + DateTime.Now.ToString "yy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss"
    base.OnPropertyChanged("Status")
    let task = async {

        do! Async.Sleep (30 * 1000) 

    }
    Async.StartImmediate(task)
    status <- "Reset done @" + DateTime.Now.ToString "yy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss"
    base.OnPropertyChanged("Status")
```

The problem is that - when I run the full WPF application - I can't see the expected delay: the final status goes straight to the output.

If I change the above `Async.StartImmediate(task)` to `Async.RunSynchronously(task)`, of course I see the delay in progress, but the application gets freezed, so this is not what I want.

If I rearrange it as

```
member this.RunSetStatus() =
    status <- "Start resetting @" + DateTime.Now.ToString "yy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss"
    base.OnPropertyChanged("Status")
    let task = async {

        do! Async.Sleep (30 * 1000) 

        status <- "Reset done @" + DateTime.Now.ToString "yy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss"
        base.OnPropertyChanged("Status")

    }
    Async.StartImmediate(task)
```

I get an error

> The member or object constructor 'OnPropertyChanged' is not
>   accessible. Private members may only be accessed from within the
>   declaring type. Protected members may only be accessed from an
>   extending type and cannot be accessed from inner lambda expressions.

### Edit (Continuation)

Finally, I've also tried this

```
member this.RunSetStatus() =
    status <- "Start resetting @" + DateTime.Now.ToString "yy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss"
    base.OnPropertyChanged("Status")
    let task = async {

        do! Async.Sleep (30 * 1000) 

    }
    Async.StartWithContinuations(task, 
        (fun _ -> this.Status <- "Reset done @" + DateTime.Now.ToString "yy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss"),
        (fun _ -> this.Status <- "Operation failed."),
        (fun _ -> this.Status <- "Operation canceled."))
```

but the application crashes with an ArgumentException

Stack Trace

> Application: MyFuncWPF.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description:
>   The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception
>   Info: System.ArgumentException Stack:    at
>   MVVM.ViewModel.ViewModelBase.OnPropertyChanged[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]
>   at FuncViewModel.MyFuncViewModel.set_Status(System.String)    at
>   .$MyVMLib+RunSetStatus@20.Invoke(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit)
>   at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Control.CancellationTokenOps+StartWithContinuations@1274[[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Invoke(System.__Canon)    at
>   .$Control.loop@430-52(Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Trampoline,
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit,Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FakeUnitValue>)
>   at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Trampoline.ExecuteAction(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2)
>   at .$Control+-ctor@507.Invoke(System.Object) 
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object

### Edit 2 - found the issue

I had to use the following - more simple - overload of `OnPropertyChanged` (they are both implemented and working in C# as per this [source code](https://giuliohome.wordpress.com/2016/10/27/a-simple-viewmodel-base-in-c/))

```
    member this.Status 
        with get() =
            status
        and set(value) =
             status <- value
             base.OnPropertyChanged("Status")
```

Comment: why not just use `FsVM`?

Comment: or even `Gjallarhorn`?

Comment: https://amazingant.com/blog/2014/12/08/FSharp-and-WPF/

Comment: and http://marisks.net/2015/04/27/f-sharp-xaml-application-mvvm-vs-mvc/

Comment: about [Gjallarhorn](http://reedcopsey.github.io/Gjallarhorn/)

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in [this blog post](http://tomasp.net/blog/async-non-blocking-gui.aspx/)? Specifically, using the swtiching parts from 'Switching between threads' and then using `Async.RunSynchronously`

Comment: the part that is written in C#...can you show it?

Comment: I ask, cause I reproduced your code and it works fine.

Comment: @GoFunctional if you want to use the UI thread (i.e. not have the app 'freeze'), surely you need to do the delaying 'work' on another thread? I can't see how you're going to do all of this on one thread.

Comment: Yeah, working fine. I see update after 30sec. You tried to write `ViemModelBase` in F#?

Comment: Yeah...I'm sure. Image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3UFQr.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the exception is that the function of F# cannot be represented as `MemberExpression`:

```
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> selectorExpression)
    {
        if (selectorExpression == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("selectorExpression");
        MemberExpression body = selectorExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (body == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("The body must be a member expression");
        OnPropertyChanged(body.Member.Name);
    }
```

In the debugger you'll see that the exception you get is actually - "The body must be a member expression".

Your first code :

```
member this.RunSetStatus() =
    status <- "Reset @" + DateTime.Now.ToString "yy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss"
    base.OnPropertyChanged("Status")
```

works since you are not using the setter of property `Status`.

So you need to use a different overload.

Comment: @GoFunctional irrespective of the various C# interop issues, is there any reason not to use just plain old [Async.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.start-method-%5Bfsharp%5D)?

Comment: @Go Functional if you will have any questions feel free to ask